# symfony backend.php links

Tags: symfony1, hyperlink, backend

I've uploaded my first symfony project to a server.
If I go to the admin page (backend.php) everything is works goot, until I click a link...
then Symfony can't find the page... what should I change for correct links from backend.php.

Comment: What is the URL of the link that's not working? What is the URL of the admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check if you're using the 'script name' in generated URL's.

The file `/apps/backend/config/settings.yml` should contain a setting `no_script_name` for your selected environment.

If the value is `true`, the scriptname (`backend.php`) is stripped from generated URL's.
In that case you should have a .htaccess RewriteRule or something which selects the appropriate frontend controller.

So if's you want URL's like: http://www.example.com/backend.php/module/action set the property to `false`. For URL's like http://backend.example.com/module/action set it to `true`.